# retrieving java swing JFrame icons

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to retrieve the minimize, maximize and close icons for the JFrame from the native look and feel.

I able to do this for the InternalFrame icons like so:

```
icon = UIManager.getIcon("InternalFrame.maximizeIcon");
```

However, I need the JFrame icons.  I don't see any keys in the look and feel for JFrame icons.  How do I access them?

thanks

Comment: Well the reason I want it is because I am creating a custom TitleBar to my JFrame that has more than just the title and native icons.  So I wanted to make it look as close to the normal title bar as possible with my added components on it.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, you can't.

The native look and feels delegate to a native renderer/peer which is not accessible from within Java

There might a means from JNI/JNA but I'm not aware of any

Comment: Too bad, it sure would be handy

Comment: @springcorn I agree with you there